# Interactive Dismiss ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, animation, interactive

I have a storyboard like that :

[image]

Article View is presented from segue and animation :

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

    if segue.identifier == "showArticleFromArticles" {
        let ViewToShow = segue.destinationViewController as! ArticleView
        ViewToShow.articleToShow = ArticleToShow2
        ViewToShow.transitioningDelegate = self
    }

}
```

My animation :

```
class TransitionManager: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning, UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate, UIViewControllerContextTransitioning {

weak var transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?

var sourceViewController: UIViewController! {
    didSet {
        print("set")
        print(sourceViewController)
        enterPanGesture = UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer()
        enterPanGesture.addTarget(self, action:"panned:")
        enterPanGesture.edges = UIRectEdge.Left
        let newSource = sourceViewController as! ArticleView
        newSource.WebView.addGestureRecognizer(enterPanGesture)
    }
}

let duration    = 1.0
var presenting  = true
var originFrame = CGRectNull

private var didStartedTransition = false
private var animated = false
private var interactive = false
private var AnimationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle(rawValue: 1)
private var didFinishedTransition = false
private var percentTransition: CGFloat = 0.0
private var enterPanGesture: UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer!

func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

    // get reference to our fromView, toView and the container view that we should perform the transition in
    let container = transitionContext.containerView()
    let fromView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewKey)!
    let toView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextToViewKey)!

    // set up from 2D transforms that we'll use in the animation
    let offScreenRight = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(container!.frame.width, 0)
    let offScreenLeft = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(container!.frame.width, 0)

    // start the toView to the right of the screen
    toView.transform = offScreenRight

    // add the both views to our view controller
    container!.addSubview(toView)
    container!.addSubview(fromView)

    // get the duration of the animation
    // DON'T just type '0.5s' -- the reason why won't make sense until the next post
    // but for now it's important to just follow this approach
    let duration = self.transitionDuration(transitionContext)

    // perform the animation!
    // for this example, just slid both fromView and toView to the left at the same time
    // meaning fromView is pushed off the screen and toView slides into view
    // we also use the block animation usingSpringWithDamping for a little bounce
    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.8, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromRight, animations: {

        fromView.transform = offScreenLeft
        toView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity

        }, completion: { finished in

            // tell our transitionContext object that we've finished animating
            transitionContext.completeTransition(true)

    })
}

func transitionDuration(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> NSTimeInterval {
    return duration
}

func startInteractiveTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
    interactive = true


    // get reference to our fromView, toView and the container view that we should perform the transition in
    let container = transitionContext.containerView()
    let fromView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewKey)!
    let toView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextToViewKey)!

    // set up from 2D transforms that we'll use in the animation
    let offScreenRight = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(container!.frame.width, 0)
    let offScreenLeft = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(container!.frame.width, 0)

    // start the toView to the right of the screen
    toView.transform = offScreenRight

    // add the both views to our view controller
    container!.addSubview(toView)
    container!.addSubview(fromView)

    // get the duration of the animation
    // DON'T just type '0.5s' -- the reason why won't make sense until the next post
    // but for now it's important to just follow this approach
    let duration = self.transitionDuration(transitionContext)

    // perform the animation!
    // for this example, just slid both fromView and toView to the left at the same time
    // meaning fromView is pushed off the screen and toView slides into view
    // we also use the block animation usingSpringWithDamping for a little bounce
    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.8, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromRight, animations: {

        fromView.transform = offScreenLeft
        toView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity

        }, completion: { finished in

            // tell our transitionContext object that we've finished animating
            transitionContext.completeTransition(true)

    })


}

func containerView() -> UIView? {
    return sourceViewController?.view
}

func viewControllerForKey(key: String) -> UIViewController? {
    return sourceViewController?.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(key)
}

func viewForKey(key: String) -> UIView? {
    return sourceViewController?.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(key).view
}

func initialFrameForViewController(vc: UIViewController) -> CGRect {
    return vc.view.frame
}

func finalFrameForViewController(vc: UIViewController) -> CGRect {
    return vc.view.frame
}

func isAnimated() -> Bool {
    return animated
}

func isInteractive() -> Bool {
    return interactive
}

func presentationStyle() -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return AnimationStyle!
}

func completeTransition(didComplete: Bool) {
    didFinishedTransition = didComplete
}

func updateInteractiveTransition(percentComplete: CGFloat) {
    percentTransition = percentComplete
}

func finishInteractiveTransition() {
    completeTransition(true)
}

func cancelInteractiveTransition() {
    completeTransition(true)
}

func transitionWasCancelled() -> Bool {
    return didFinishedTransition
}

func targetTransform() -> CGAffineTransform {
    return CGAffineTransform()
}

func panned(pan: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    //print(pan.translationInView(sourceViewController!.view))
    switch pan.state {
    case .Began:
        animated = true
        didStartedTransition = true
        didFinishedTransition = false
        sourceViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        if transitionContext != nil {
            startInteractiveTransition(transitionContext!)
        }
        break
    case .Changed:
        percentTransition = CGFloat(pan.translationInView(sourceViewController!.view).x / sourceViewController!.view.frame.width)
        print(percentTransition)
        updateInteractiveTransition(percentTransition)
        break
    case .Ended, .Failed, .Cancelled:
        animated = false
        didStartedTransition = false
        didFinishedTransition = true
        finishInteractiveTransition()
        break
    case .Possible:
        break
    }
}
```

}

From Article View, I call dismiss view like that :

```
@IBAction func Quit(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

and :

```
func animationControllerForDismissedController(dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    transition.presenting = false
    return transition
}
```

And i add the PanGesture like that :

```
let transition = TransitionManager()
self.transition.sourceViewController = self
```

But Pan Gesture just dismiss the view, and Interactive is not available
Because i call :

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

during UIPanGestureRecognizer.began

How can I do this ?

I am using Xcode 7, Swift 2, iOS 9

Thanks !

Comment: VC transitions is the most laughably complex failure of an API i've ever seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution :

i should just use

```
startInteractiveTransition
```

to instantiate some things

and use :

```
func updateInteractiveTransition(percentComplete: CGFloat) {
    if self.reverse {
        print(percentComplete)
        self.tovc.view.frame.origin.x = (self.fromvc.view.frame.maxX * (percentComplete)) - self.fromvc.view.frame.maxX
    }
}
```

to custom my transition.

Answer (score 0):

Easy to use, Just inherent Your UIViewController with InteractiveViewController and you are done
[InteractiveViewController](https://github.com/SarwarShoaib/Interactive)

call method showInteractive() from your controller to show as Interactive.

[image]